# Enabling HTTP/2 Support in daphne with django

Tags: django, daphne

When I run this command

```
command: daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem server.asgi:application --port 8000 --bind 0.0.0.0
```

The error I get is as follows

> Starting server at ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem,
> tcp:port=8000:interface=0.0.0.0 HTTP/2 support enabled Configuring
> endpoint ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=crt.pem Traceback (most
> recent call last): ...
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> '/usr/src/app/crt.pem'

Can someone tell how to fix this error?

Answer (score 4):

Install tls and http2. I see that you have everything installed. This is for clarification.

```
pip install -U 'Twisted[tls,http2]'
```

You can use your own privateKey and certKey for testing.

I will run commands in the /home/user/Documents/ssl/

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt
```

Run the application

```
daphne -e ssl:8000:privateKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.key:certKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.crt myapp.asgi:application
```

Output

```
user@debian:~/Documents/pythonWeb/myapp$ daphne -e ssl:8000:privateKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.key:certKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.crt myapp.asgi:application
    2022-02-04 18:49:12,726 INFO     Starting server at ssl:8000:privateKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.key:certKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.crt
    2022-02-04 18:49:12,726 INFO     HTTP/2 support enabled
    2022-02-04 18:49:12,726 INFO     Configuring endpoint ssl:8000:privateKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.key:certKey=/home/user/Documents/ssl/selfsigned.crt
    2022-02-04 18:49:12,733 INFO     Listening on TCP address 0.0.0.0:8000
    2022-02-04 18:49:27,644 INFO     file_cache is only supported with oauth2client<4.0.0
    192.168.1.106:50128 - - [04/Feb/2022:18:49:32] "GET /stream_1/" 200 2510
    192.168.1.106:58251 - - [04/Feb/2022:18:49:32] "WSCONNECTING /ws/chat/stream_1/" - -
    connect
```

If you have ".pem" files from Let's Encrypt, paste them in place of the self-signed ones.